# Copy data from one Column of data to another Dataverse and run whenever a new row is added in Type column

Tags: powerbi, dynamics-crm, dataverse, powerapps-modeldriven

I have a Dataverse with a column Type, called 'Part Type'

I also have a Dataverse called 'Maintenance Parts' which has a column for Name which is currently blank.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can anyone tell me the steps and expressions needed to copy data from Type column and paste it into Name column also run whenever a new row is added in Type column?

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Please visit the [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research or search for related topics on SO. If you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output. In case your question is not about programming I suggest posting your question on one of the Microsoft's Power Platform forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a real-time workflow that will handle Create of the record and update the record with the value from your dropdown.